# How do I turn off WordPress errors and just have regular old php errors?

Tags: errors, wp-error

If I use the constants, I still get the WP errors.  I don’t want WP shadowed box and custom messages and all that.  Just plain old PHP errors.

In wp-config.php I have this:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

 ini_set("display_errors", true);
 ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

but I still get the formatted wordpress errors.
[image]

I want just the normal php errors:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper and easy way to disable the WordPress fatal error handler is by adding this to the `wp-config.php` file:

```php
define( 'WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER', true );
```

And that line, along with the code in your post, will give you the normal PHP errors.

- There's an alternate way of disabling the WordPress fatal error handler (using the `wp_fatal_error_handler_enabled` filter), but please check the [`wp_is_fatal_error_handler_enabled()` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_fatal_error_handler_enabled/#description) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a *wp_die_handler* filter in your theme's function.php. You call and execute PHP die() inside the filter, which should end the whole execution. You are then left with a plain error printed on your web page.

```
add_filter( 'wp_die_handler', function( $message, $title = '', $args = array() ) {
   die();
}, 99 );
```